# Why does the C++11 move constructor copy by value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I thought the following example would have the same result as `std::map::emplace()`, but it didn't:

```
struct MoveTest {
    MoveTest():
        var(true)
    {
        cout << "ctor: " << static_cast<void*>(&var) << endl;
    }

    MoveTest(MoveTest&& mt):
        var(std::move(mt.var))
    {
        cout << "move ctor: " << static_cast<void*>(&var) << endl;
    }

    bool var;
};


int main() {
    map<int, MoveTest> mtest;
    mtest.insert(make_pair(1, MoveTest()));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
ctor: 0x7fff12e4e19b
move ctor: 0x7fff12e4e194
move ctor: 0x25f3034
```

The `MoveTest::var` has a different address in each move. It doesn't look like a "*move*". What's wrong in my code or understanding?

Comment: you cannot test move by taking address. what moved is the internal struct, which is not visible to you

Comment: Move construction doesn't do what you think. What it does, is make the value at the destination equal to the value initially at the source, in a way that is permitted to modify the source. It doesn't change the address of either the destination or the source. The `var` data member is part of the the `MoveTest` object, and its address is always somewhere within the object it belongs to.

Comment: cause your move constructor isn't moving anything. copying a bool is just copying a bool, you will get different addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MoveTest as you've defined it, there's not really much a move ctor (or assignment operator) can optimize (or do in general--all it can really do is copy from source go destination).

Moving is mostly a big win when an object contains a pointer to a bunch of external memory that's (for example) allocated on the heap. In this case, the move ctor/assignment operator can basically do a shallow copy (i.e., just grab the pointer from the moved-from object) instead of a deep copy (copying all the data referred to by that pointer).

For example:

```
class move_tst {
    int *buffer;
    static const int size = 1024 * 1024;
public:
    move_tst() {        
        buffer = new int[size];
        std::iota(buffer, buffer + size, 0);
    }

    move_tst(move_tst const &other) {
        buffer = new int[size];
        std::copy_n(other.buffer, size, buffer);
    }

#ifdef MOVE
    move_tst(move_tst &&other) {
        buffer = other.buffer;
        other.buffer = nullptr;
    }
#endif

    ~move_tst() { 
        delete [] buffer;
    }
};
```

Caveat: I've used a raw invocation of `new` and a raw pointer here so nothing else gets involved and we wouldn't (for example) get move semantics courtesy of a smart pointer. For normal code under normal circumstances, you should *not* be using either (raw pointer or raw invocation of `new`, I mean).

Edit: as far as what `std::move` does, it doesn't actually do a move itself--it just signals that you no longer care about a value, so it's eligible to be the source of a move, even if that destroys its value.

For example, with the class above, you could do a test like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    move_tst src;
    move_tst dst =src;
}
```

...and compare it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    move_tst src;
    move_tst dst = std::move(src);
}
```

Without the `std::move`, `dst` will be created as a copy of `src`, but with the `std::move`, it'll be able to do a move from `src` to `dst`.

Comment: Well, I agree what you said. However, I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. The example in my question is not intended to *optimize* anything. It would be great if you could explain what's wrong in my understanding of what std::move does :)

Comment: @YZ.learner When I first discovered `std::move` I kept thinking of `std::swap` and confusing myself :)

Comment: @kfsone: there is a connection though, in that pretty much all moves could validly be implemented as a swap. It's just that it would be kind of surprising. You expect that any resources associated with the target will be released, not left hanging around in the source.

Answer (score 1):

Your log simply tells that you create a temporary MoveTest instance with the default constructor

```
MoveTest()
```

which is then copied elsewhere, inside a pair object

```
make_pair(1, MoveTest())
```

and copied again somewhere inside the map object

```
mtest.insert(make_pair(1, MoveTest()));
```

There are three constructor invocations for three distinct MoveTest instances, each with its own address. As already well explained, whether the constructors are move constructors or old style copy constructors doesn't matter.

Did you expect some of the copies to be optimized away? With nontrivial code in the constructors it becomes unlikely; in particular, reading **&var** is a good reason to avoid shortcuts.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting those two move ctors wouldn't allocate new memory , because that's what "move" (instead of "copy") sounds like.